# Why does the Convair 990 produce this howling sound during landing?

Tags: jet-engine, convair-880

Watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXl9AgWTb0w) of a landing Convair 990, one can hear a whooshing howl at about 0:11-0:12, as it flares just prior to touchdown (not to be confused with the run-of-the-mill howling that you can hear from 0:13 on as the engines spool down *after* touchdown); what makes this sound?  Does the CJ805-23 engine have a different sound profile than other engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you hear at 0:11-0:12 is just the sound of the engines being reduced to idle thrust, and the doppler effect as the aircraft passes your position.

I have heard that sound hundreds(maybe thousands) of times. It is very normal, and sounds just like all jets of that generation.

Here are more examples:

[Skymaster DC-8-63F Landing](https://youtu.be/5ucxYuUumn8?t=10)

[707 ! Touch & Go, Depature, Landing.](https://youtu.be/mJ_P1UaBbds?t=210)

[Boeing 707 Landing - Smokey!](https://youtu.be/HBFnuaePwLQ?t=30)